# How to get summation

Tags: java

How to get summation from `i =1` to `n` in java without using loops.
Need to get the summation for parameter passed when user execute the code.

**Note:** Numbers will be passed as a parameters

Comment: `N * (N + 1) / 2`

Comment: Whats with the dislike for loops?

Comment: you can use recursion

Comment: Recursion for the win.

Comment: Well I don't understand - the **only badge you have is citizen partol** and you ask something like this?

Comment: Also, why no loops?  Can the solution use recursive method calls?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Post an answer?

Comment: @DuncanJones this is OP's homework to find it...

Comment: This isn't actually a terrible question, not really a programming question but still. In hindsight @LuiggiMendoza solution is much better than a loop

Comment: Gauss is disappointed.

Comment: Can somebody explain me, how is possible, that you've got 3.7k reputation even when you're asking so dummy questions?

Comment: @Dworza: The OP has only 9 rep

Comment: @MarcoForberg Haha...sorry..my bad :D I accidentalty looked at the profile of the person who has edited it :D

Comment: @Dworza: Things like this happen ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you could go for recursion:

```
public long getSummation(long n) {
    if(n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values below 0 are not supported.");
    }
    if(n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return n + getSummation(n - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @downvoters: care to explain?

Comment: Care to review the other two answers and the most upvoted comment?

Comment: By the way, recursive method just hides a loop, that's the reason why other two answer like this were downvoted and deleted.

Comment: well i looked at the other answers and comments before posting this answer, but neither of them makes this answer wrong...

Comment: What part of *recursive method just hides a loop* didn't you understand? Note in OP's question: *How to get summation without using loops*.

Comment: the fact that you wrote hides a recursion before

Comment: well if you consider this a joke...

Comment: I don't see any problems with this answer. +1 from me

Comment: @vmironov then read the question again...

Comment: btw where can i read up that recursion is a loop?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, do you really think that recursion and loop are the same?

Comment: @vmironov in this case, yes. If you think they are not, show me the proof :).

Comment: I think that the compiler would optimize this into a loop, but I am not sure.  Anyway this is an implementation detail and not the same as hiding a loop.  Luigi Mendoza, how are you sure the implementation of the formulaic answer n(n+1)/2 does not use a loop? Can you prove it, for every single JVM implementation?

Comment: @emory a mathematic formula don't use a loop for its implementation. It behaves as O(1), while this recursion behaves as O(N).

Comment: well putting runtime behaviour to side, this looks like a typical homework question and for educational purposes it be worth to show up some different approach to the problem. When it comes to programming knowledge he learns nothing from just putting in that formula. With this answer the OP might have learnt something about recursion and if it's only that it's not the best approach for every problem. @johnchen902: calm down, get yourself some manners and a dictionary...

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza O(1) versus O(n) does not make sense without specifying the basic operation.  In the recursive solution the basic operation is if I understand correctly addition.  In the formulaic solution the basic operation is if I understand correctly multiplication.  No matter how big n is there will only be 1 multiplication and one division.  How does java implement multiplication.  (I don't know.)  If it is by repeated addition and we use that as the basic operation, then both solutions are O(n) and the formulaic answer is hiding a loop.

Comment: @emory is not Java who implements the add or multiplication operations...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza whether this solution is implemented as a loop or not is decided by java, so I don't think it is fair to say that this solution is just hiding the loop

Comment: mm i think that compiler can pass this for iterative mode if it's lineal the recursion, your recursion is not lineal

Answer (score 7):

You can sum numbers **from 1 to n** using the equation `(N * (N+1)) /2` . This is without using any loops. You can find the tutorial [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Sum-the-Integers-from-1-to-N).

Comment: It's easy to check the most upvoted comment and post the answer :).

Comment: I started writing the answer before I read the comment, but I get your point...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You should have posted it as an answer ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I was searching about the mathematician who come up with the formula on internet, it is a great story. Apart of that, it is no big deal...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it's Gauss!!

Comment: He was in primary school: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes

Answer (score 3):

You must use the mathematic formula `N * (N + 1) / 2`:

```
public long getSummation(long n) {
    return (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
}
```

This is heavily explained in wikipedia: [1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Sorry, I don't remember the mathematician who comes with this idea.

Comment: that's true but recursion is better because I need to get the parameter from user input (and recursion is applicable with arrays and other types).

Comment: always in school told the same history, gauss at 5 years , the teacher gives them an excercise to count 1+2..+99+100 , and gauss solved it in 5 minutes.. using that formula , (100+1) (99+2) .. 101*50  :)